# How to specify a condition on all path elements in XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Here is my XML:

```
<a>
  <a>
    <a stop="">
      <a>
        <b/>
      </a>
    </a>
  </a>
</a>
```

I need to select element `<b>` if the path to it doesn't have `<a>` with `@stop`. It should be something like this (assume I'm already staying at some `<a>` in the tree):

```
a//[not(@stop)]b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> select element `<b>` if the path to it doesn't have `<a>` with `@stop`

I would read that as:

```
//b[not(ancestor::a/@stop)]
```